# How to not display all values on x axis when format is date? ggplot R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame as follows.

```
TIME                 PRICE
2013-01-01 23:55:03 446.6167
2013-01-01 23:55:02 441.0114
2013-01-01 23:54:59 446.7600
```

I want to plot the following as a scatter plot in R using ggplot. The times are unique.

I want to plot the data showing x labels only once in every 30 minutes. Can someone help me?

```
class(inter_1$TRANSACTION_TIME)
[1] "factor"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to [this](https://jonkimanalyze.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/ggplot2-time-series-axis-control-breaks-label-limitshttpsjonkimanalyze-wordpress-comwp-adminedit-phpinline-edit/) for the usage of `scale_x_datetime` for 30 minutes break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your "TIME" column to a "time" format, since now it is a factor. Something like this would work:

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(TIME = anytime(TIME)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##                  TIME    PRICE
##                <dttm>    <dbl>
## 1 2013-01-01 22:55:03 446.6167
## 2 2013-01-01 22:55:02 441.0114
```

You see that now "TIME" is a "date-time" variable. Then, you can adjust the x-axis using `scale_x_date_time`.

HTH.